# what's the start point to develop a real-time chat app using react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'd like to try to develop a simple chat room app, it might have the real-time message interaction, what's the important thing I should notice and I will do first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I highly recommend using [react-native-gifted-chat](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat) for the UI, and using [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) for the real-time connection.

You will want to think about how the user will enter the chat. Will there be a message board, will there be group/one-to-one chat, will the users be able to send images, push notifications, in-app new message alerts, read receipts, etc.

I have a simple chat that I built using RN-gifted-chat and firebase that you can look at for reference: https://github.com/liplylie/ReactNativeChatImageAudio